# Duplicate UItableViewCell, Rows of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Here tableview after scrolling 2 3 times full up and down add images to all cells. Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"HomeCell"] ;
}

VenueDC *venueObj = [subSubCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblName.text = venueObj.name;
if ([venueObj.imagesArray count] > 0) {
    [cell.ivVenue setImage:venueObj.ivVenue];
    [cell.ivVenue setHidden:NO];
    cell.lblName.frame = CGRectMake(80, cell.lblName.frame.origin.y, 200, cell.lblName.frame.size.height);
}
venueObj = nil;


return  cell;
}
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Image is only in one object, on first load it shows one cell with image, but after scrolling it starts showing images on other cell too.

Comment: Try This Thread answer, may be it will help you.
:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535637/reusablecellwithidentifier-issue-in-cellforrowatindexpath/10535788#10535788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it like this, first i set the lblName frame to its original position, so it reset its position everytime the cell is used

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell"];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (HomeCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

VenueDC *venueObj = nil;
venueObj = [subSubCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblName.text = venueObj.name;
[cell.ivVenue setHidden:YES];
cell.lblName.frame = CGRectMake(20 , 19, 250, 20);
if (venueObj.ivVenue) {
    [cell.ivVenue setImage:venueObj.ivVenue];
    [cell.ivVenue setHidden:NO];
    cell.lblName.frame = CGRectMake(80, cell.lblName.frame.origin.y, 200, cell.lblName.frame.size.height);
} 
return  cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCells` get reused, which is what the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: method does. To save memory the `UITableView` only instantiates as many cells as it is possible to see at any given point, and then just keeps on reusing them. Because of this you should always clean up your cells before reuse, that is reset all its content to `nil`.

If you are using a custom table view like in your case `HomeCell` then override -(void)`prepareForReuse` and set up the image to nil there.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your cell is reuse so write this code:

```
HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (HomeCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ur answer helped i upvote, but the problem i got solved see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need an `else` statement:

```
else {
venueObj = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"HomeCell"] ;
}

VenueDC *venueObj = [subSubCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblName.text = venueObj.name;
    [cell.ivVenue setImage:nil];

if ([venueObj.imagesArray count] > 0) {
    [cell.ivVenue setImage:venueObj.ivVenue];
    [cell.ivVenue setHidden:NO];
    cell.lblName.frame = CGRectMake(80, cell.lblName.frame.origin.y, 200, cell.lblName.frame.size.height);
}
venueObj = nil;


return  cell;
}
```

Comment: now its not showing the images but, this image as u can see was hidden, so it does go in the "If" and moves the lblName forward

Comment: check if the image is there or not..if not then dont set the frame of lblname. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add only one line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

**And change**

```
HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: This will have memory issue. what do you think? It wont reuse any cell with another but with the same index path in the same section resulting of creating as many no of cells as no of rows present in the tableview. Correct me if  i am wrong.

Comment: yes u r write ..in this code it create new cell when user scroll tableview not reuse older cell ;)

Comment: does it necessary?? we can create the same effect with reusing the cells resulting in lot less memory usage then this code will occupy..

Comment: but in some case it is helpful . i know that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call only visible cell.. it is not call for invisible cell...when user scroll and display cell then it not create new one (cell) but reuse it :)

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier this will only works if cellIdentifier is same. But in your case it is unique for each and every cell . It will only reuse if it encounter with same cellIdentifier. ie if the user scrolls to last and then again to top. The first cell will reuse only with first cell previously created. which is meaningless. Take a large array like 25 elements and then check how much cells being created. It will be exactly 25 if the user scrolls to last of the tableview.