# Make UIImageView fill the whole UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do you make the whole UITableViewCell a custom image? I do it for prototyping purposes and I can't find where to start. I basically need 3 UITableViewCells with the same image - so they all are reusable cells.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image) is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is : `backgroundView` property of `UITableViewCell`

**You can do it like this :**

```
-(void)  tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
   willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
{
    static UIImage* bgImage = nil;
    if (bgImage == nil) {
        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] retain];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage] autorelease];
}
```

**Or Simply Use :**

```
((UIImageView*)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customBackground"];
((UIImageView*)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBackground"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If u are planning to change a lot of things in the cells I will go this way:

You can create a custom cell class and design it with the a full cell image background. Then you will create cells of that cell class in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

If you just need to add and image as background and you dont need anything else then just create an imageview with the proper size and add it as a subview of the cellview

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you'll have to create a customized UITableViewCell. You can create a cell and assign background image to it.

This background image will be used for all the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cell's **backgrounView** to add an Image or you can use cell's **contentView** and add the subViews to the cell Starting with an Image look at [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535637/reusablecellwithidentifier-issue-in-cellforrowatindexpath/10535788#10535788) thread you will get an idea

[UITableViewCell Refrence](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938)